# How do I insert HTML elements into an HTML file with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

**WHAT I ALREADY HAVE**
I use the following for extracting data from an HTML file.
This example lists all Table Rows within an HTML file

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim TRelements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TRelement As HTMLTableCell
Dim r As Long
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Navigate filePath
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set HTMLdoc = .Document
End With
Set TRelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")
```

This allows me to pinpoint data in the following way (5th row, 1st cell), Example:

```
A = TRelements.Item(5).ChildNodes.Item(1).innerText
```

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR**
I'd like to insert a new cell (TD-element) at the beginning of a row (TR-element)

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

| NAME | SURNAME |
| --- | --- |
| Walter | White |

New TD-element for DOB

| DOB | NAME | SURNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09-07-58 | Walter | White |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example below I use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and [Element.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) to insert the new cells.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TRelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TRelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim r As Long
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .navigate filePath
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTMLdoc = .document
    End With        
    
    Set TRelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    Dim TR As HTMLTableRow
    Set TR = TRelements(0)
    TR.insertAdjacentHTML "afterbegin", "<TH>DOB</TH>"
    
    Dim TD As HTMLTableCell
    Set TD = HTMLdoc.createElement("TD")
    
    Set TR = TRelements(1)
    TD.innerText = "09-07-58"
    TR.insertAdjacentElement "afterbegin", TD
    
    IE.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This subroutine will update the original file.

```
Sub OverWriteHTMLDocument(Document As HTMLDocument, FilePath As String)
    Rem VBA OpenTextFile: https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-opentextfile/
    
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 'Need to define constants manually
    Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0 'Need to define constants manually
    Dim Url As String
    Url = Replace(Document.Url, "file://", "", , , vbTextCompare)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(Url, ForWriting, True, TristateFalse)
        .WriteLine Document.DocumentElement.outerHTML
        .Close
    End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: That works, what is the proper way to save the changes to the document?

Comment: @MK01111000 Thanks for accepting my answer.  I added a  subroutine that will update the file.